# JQuery selecting li for pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am working on a pagination script and all is well apart from one small problem. I need to fire an action when the page number (li) is clicked.

The pagination is returned via ajax to a div called "result". However this div is burried amound several other divs deep - i think this may be the problem. How can fix?

Thanks

```
$('#result .pagination li').live('click', function () {
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page);
        return false;
    });
```

The full output is below with the full pagination

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Title</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>

                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Dashboard</a>
                </li>

                <li><a href="claims.php">Claims</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Claims</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        DataTables Advanced Tables

                        <div id="loading" style="float: right; display: none;">
                            <img src="images/loading.gif">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="result">
                            <!-- DATABASE RESULTS GO HERE -->
                            <ul class="pagination" id="pg">
                                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">First</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="disabled"><a>1</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">2</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">3</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">4</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">5</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">6</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">7</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">»</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#">Last</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: can you share the html... also what is the jQuery version used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery >= 1.9, so there is [no .live() method](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)

```
$(document).on('click', '#result .pagination li', function () {
    var page = $(this).attr('p');
    loadData(page);
    return false;
});
```